# Restore Firefox (smart)? keyword(s| searches)

Tags: firefox, search

I've deleted the [Firefox keyword somethings](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_keyword_searches), and I can't find an easy way to restore them. Is there some about:config setting that would do the trick, or a bookmark file that I could import with only those?

Comment: I've also had this problem. Would like to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify which Firefox version, but for the latest 3.5.x -

You can easily readd them, as well as change them or add new ones to your existing search engines.

In Firefox, go to `Manage Search Engines` from the Search Engine drop down box.

From all the listed engines you can `Edit Keyword`, or even `Restore Defaults`.

You can even add **superuser.com** search engine and give it the keyword **su**.

[image: My configured search engines]

Comment: Alright - I had no idea you could assign these to the search engines directly instead of adding it as a bookmark. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](http://johnbokma.com/firefox/keymarks-explained.html) you can import his set of smart keywords from [this file](http://johnbokma.com/firefox/keymarks.txt.gz).
While I haven't tried, I notice that those are not the defaults that come with firefox.

So my suggestion would be to reinstall firefox on top of your current installation, since it will not delete anything that's already there, and will probably add those missing keywords.

Direct link to [latest release.](http://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-3.5.6&os=win&lang=en-GB)